# How can I preserve values between WCF service methods calling?

Tags: wcf, static

I have this WCF Service class:

```
public partial class OhmioSVC: IOhmioSVC_Security
{
    // Porque no funciona si la variable no es estatica?
    private static ConnectionBusiness _conn = new ConnectionBusiness();

    public ConnectionBusiness Conn
    {
        get
        {
            return _conn;
        }
    }

    public void Connect(string Usuario, string Password, string DataBase)
    {            
        Conn.ObtenerTicket (Usuario, Password, DataBase);                        
    }

    public List<Errores> GetErrors()
    {
        return Conn.MyErrors;            
    }        
}
```

As you can see, _conn is defined as static, because I need to preserve his value between calls. If I remove the "static", and call method Connect (creates the _conn object) and then call getErrores _conn variable is for some reason empty.

The problem with this is that if I miss calling "connect" method I whant to throw and exception, but _conn stills get the value from the last call. I know i'm doing something wrong here, but I don't see another alternative. Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Using a constructor that initiates a non static variable _conn does not help?

Comment: Thanks for the help.I try what you suggest. The problem is that even if I only create one instance of the service on the client and call the two methods, the constructor is fired two times instead of one. It should has something to do with how wcf services work.

Comment: You can also implement a more "pretty" solution :)
Make your service singleton, so you will not miss your variables per instance. 
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a WCF service class is instantiated for every new *session* that is created. For some bindings which do not support sessions, then a "session" spans only a single call, meaning that for two calls from the client (one for `Connect`, one for `GetErrors`), there will be two instances of the `OhmioSVC` class created, which is why if you don't specify the `ConnectionBusiness` property as static, two of them will be created and you will get the result you see.

What you need to to tell WCF that you *require* a session in your service contract. You can do that by adding the `SessionMode` property in your service contract declaration:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IOhmio_Security
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Connect(string user, string password, string db);
    [OperationContract]
    List<string> GetErrors();
}
```

If you have that, and you use a binding which does not support sessions (e.g., BasicHttpBinding), then your service will fail to open - you then need to change to a binding that supports sessions (e.g., WSHttpBinding). The code below shows an example with sessions that work:

```
public class StackOverflow_31541498
{
    class ConnectionBusiness
    {
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        public void ObtenerTicket(string user, string password, string db)
        {
            errors.Add(string.Format("ObtenerTicket called: {0}, {1}, {2}", user, password, db));
        }
        public List<string> MyErrors
        {
            get
            {
                var result = new List<string>(this.errors);
                errors.Clear();
                if (result.Count == 0)
                {
                    result.Add("No errors!");
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface IOhmio_Security
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Connect(string user, string password, string db);
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetErrors();
    }
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class OhmioSVC : IOhmio_Security
    {
        private ConnectionBusiness _conn = new ConnectionBusiness();
        public void Connect(string user, string password, string db)
        {
            _conn.ObtenerTicket(user, password, db);
        }

        public List<string> GetErrors()
        {
            return _conn.MyErrors;
        }
    }
    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        // var result = new BasicHttpBinding(); // This will not work, as it doesn't support sessions
        var result = new WSHttpBinding(); // This will work
        return result;
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(OhmioSVC), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IOhmio_Security), GetBinding(), "");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IOhmio_Security>(GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        proxy.Connect("user", "pwd", "db");
        var errors = proxy.GetErrors();
        Console.WriteLine("Errors:\n   {0}", string.Join("\n   ", errors));

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be to merge the two methods in your scenario - make `Connect` return the list of errors, this way you don't have to make a separate call to get them, and you won't have to deal with sessions.

Comment: Ok Thanks! I didn't know that. So if I left my variable as static and two different clients create separate instance of the same services, do i take the risk that the values of that variables are mixed between clients?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, any information that I need to be persistent for the client it need to be saved on client-side and send it to server on every call?

Comment: For the first: if you have a static property in your service class, it will maintain the value across multiple client invocations (as long as the service class is up - if you're hosting the WCF service under IIS, it's possible that the application may be recycled).

Comment: For the second question: no, you don't need to persist it in the client. The session is managed by WCF itself. If you run the code I posted, you'll see that the server will "remember" the client it's talking to, if it's using a binding that supports session (such as WSHttpBinding). The client code doesn't have to send any information to the server so that it can "remember" who is sending it.

Comment: This my frend is an example of an excellent answer. Well explained and you got exactly the point. Change the Binding to wsHTTPBinding and force the service to use sessions and now my constructor is called only once and I have no need of the static variable. Thank you very very much.